# Centering div that can be bigger than body

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm working on project which includes a login/register page. It's basically a white div in body which should be centered verticaly and horizontally, but sometimes can be bigger than body.

When div is small everything is okay, but when its bigger than body then I just want it to have small padding on top and bottom.

How can I achieve that ? I have been searching for answer whole day and finally I'm here. Help me people :C

```css
 #wrap {
  height: 300px;
  width: 150px;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  background: #DDD;
}

#content {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="content"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using `id` instead of `class` for styling is bad practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `min-height` instead of `height` and a small top and bottom padding on the wrapper as shown below. When the inner element is higher than the wrapper, it will extend the wrapper and additionally keep the padding .

```css
 #wrap {
  min-height: 300px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #DDD;
}
#content {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="content"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `min-height` instead of `height`, and add `padding` to top and bottom. Use `box-sizing: border-box` to prevent the padding from changing the height:

```css
.wrap {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  background: #DDD;
}

.content {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
}

/** for the demo **/
.content--small {
  height: 100px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content"> 
  </div>
</div>

<!-- for the demo -->
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content content--small"> 
  </div>
</div>
```